# MySQL 5.7 - Total quantity column for Bill of Materials

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, hierarchy

I would like to ask for a help.I use MySQL 5.7 and  I have a Bill of Materials table called BOM.

I have many columns there which I will add later to the query, but for this questionID, Name, ParentID and Quantity is important. I would like to add a calculated column totalQty to my table that will multiply children quantities with parent quantities up to the top level. here is an example of what I want to achive:

```
+-------+------+------+----------+----------+--+
|  ID   | Name | Qty  | ParentID | TotalQty |  |
+-------+------+------+----------+----------+--+
|     1 | A    |    1 |        0 |        1 |  |
|   1.1 | AA   |    2 |        1 |        2 |  |
| 1.1.1 | AAA  |    1 |      1.1 |        2 |  |
|   1.2 | AB   |    5 |        1 |        5 |  |
| 1.2.1 | ABA  |    2 |      1.2 |       10 |  |
|     2 | B    |    3 |        0 |        3 |  |
|   2.1 | BA   |    2 |        2 |        6 |  |
+-------+------+------+----------+----------+--+
```

I need this to create a list of materials used per project, so I will multiply totalQTY with unit mass and unit length to get total mass and total length of part. Then I will group and aggregate them by material type.

I have searched the forums, and I have found out that I need to use Common table expressions (CTE) for this. But I have found no explanation in plain english on how to do it for my case.

Thank you very much for any help or hint how to understand the concept.

Comment: Generated columns aren't allowed to use subqueries.

Comment: Do you want to make this a virtual column in the table, or just calculate it with a query? You can't use a subquery in the definition of a virtual column.

Comment: I just wanted to calculate it with a query and pass it to the datatable. However, I cannot use "With" in MySQL 5.7, I would need to upgrade the whole database to 8.0 to do that. In order not to deal with temporary tables and make things more complicated, I solve the issue programatically in vb.net. Thanks anyway.

Comment: RIght, CTE is not available until 8.0. Recursive queries are very difficult before that.